# why do we have use Model.new for def new and def create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

following the RailsTutorial book (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-signup_form)

we have the following snippet:

```
def new
 @user = User.new
end

def create
 @user = User.new(user_params)
 ....
end
```

why do we need to recreate the model, if the user goes to /users/new def new is called and @user variable is initialzed, but on post request (def create), User.new is recalled, why is this? if we are going to create a new user model on create then why create it in def new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every request will generate a new instance of controller. `#new` has an instance, and `#create` has another one, and another hit on `#new` create another new one. These controllers instances are different, and their instance variable `@user` is different.

Comment: @Saad And even if you had the same controller, there's really nothing for `create` to  "reuse" from the original `User` instance, since it hasn't been saved and the `post` can come with entirely new data.

Answer (score 1):

`new` doesn't save the model to the database. It just instantiates a temporary instance.

So when the *action* `new` calls `User.new`, it creates a tremporary variable with no values in it - which it then passes to the view to help display the form... and then that temporary variable gets thrown away.

When you hit the submit button on the form, the form params gets sent to the `create` action in the application which then calls `User.new` with the params to instantiate a fresh model - with the values passed in the form.

Your create method will usually then call `save` on the model which will save the data into the database.